# Why is Dir not recognized as a method in my script?

Tags: vbscript, wildcard

I am working on a VBS script to send emails automatically through outlook. There will be 2 files in the folder each time the script runs and I need it to attach the one that has "Formatted in the name. I tried using the Dir method so I could wildcard the file path but it throws an error saying that Dir is an undefined variable.

Here's my code:

```
Option Explicit

Const olMailItem = 0

Sub SendBasicEmail()
    Dim olApp: Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim olEmail: Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Dim strLocation
    strLocation = Dir("C:\Users\MChambers\Desktop\Pricing Reports\Pricing_Report_*Formatted.xslx")

    If strLocation <> "" Then
        With olEmail 
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "generic"
            .Attachments.Add (strLocation)
            .To = "myemail"
            .Subject = "Subject"

            .send
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, unlike VBA and VB6, VBScript doesn't have a `Dir` function. You should be able to create your own helper function that uses [Regular Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html) instead.

**Here's an example:**

```
Option Explicit

Function FindFirstFile(strDirPath, strPattern)
    Dim strResult

    Dim objRegExp, objMatches
    Set objRegExp = New RegExp
    objRegExp.Pattern = strPattern
    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True

    Dim objFso, objFolder, objFile
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirPath)

    For Each objFile in objFolder.Files
        Set objMatches = objRegExp.Execute(objFile.Name)
        If objMatches.Count > 0 Then
            strResult = objMatches(0).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    FindFirstFile = strResult
End Function
```

**Usage:**

```
Dim strPattern
strPattern = "Pricing_Report_.*Formatted\.xslx"
strLocation = FindFirstFile("C:\Users\MChambers\Desktop\Pricing Reports\", strPattern)

If strLocation <> "" Then
    ' Do something here.
End If
```

**Note:**

Just like the `Dir` function, this will *only* return the filename. However, you seem to be trying to get the full path instead. If so, you may replace the following line:

```
FindFirstFile = strResult
```

..with something like:

```
If Len(strResult) > 0 Then
    If Right(strDirPath, 1) <> "\" Then strDirPath = strDirPath & "\"
    strResult = strDirPath & strResult
End If
FindFirstFile = strResult
```

Comment: Excellent answer, nicely explained.